# BluetoothChat Android Example Runtime Error

Tags: java, android, eclipse

It's my first time to play something with Android und Bluetooth. So i tried the example `BluetoothChat` on android.com, but i had some issues.

Thats the LogCat Output:

```
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.android.BluetoothChat/com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.BluetoothChat-2.apk]
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1569)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.android.BluetoothChat-2.apk]
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:240)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:551)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
07-11 10:51:40.000: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(853):     ... 11 more
07-11 10:51:40.010: WARN/ActivityManager(133):   Force finishing activity com.example.android.BluetoothChat/.BluetoothChat
07-11 10:51:40.510: WARN/ActivityManager(133): Activity pause timeout for HistoryRecord{406a4340 com.example.android.BluetoothChat/.BluetoothChat}
```

I know this should be really easy, but i really have no idea, how to fix that.
The manfiestfile looks like this (its the orginal):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- Copyright (C) 2009 The Android Open Source Project

     Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
     you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
     You may obtain a copy of the License at

          http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

     Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
     distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
     WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
     See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
     limitations under the License.
-->
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="com.example.android.BluetoothChat"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-sdk minSdkVersion="6" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />

    <application android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:icon="@drawable/app_icon" >
        <activity android:name=".BluetoothChat"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".DeviceListActivity"
                  android:label="@string/select_device"
                  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" />
    </application>
</manifest>
```

The rest of the files are orginal, too. Hope you can help me. I could not import the orginal files, so i created an new one an replaced the directories and the mainfest file. Maybe there is the problem.

Comment: I think u need to check package name. If everything is exactly same there shouldn't be any problem.

Comment: can you show the directory listing of your project !!

Answer (score 0):

It fails to find the class `com.example.android.BluetoothChat.BluetoothChat`. Note that the *package name* already contains `BluetoothChat`. Also note that class names are case-sensitive, so if your class is in a package `com.example.android.bluetoothchat`, then it won't work!

Comment: case-sensitive is not the problem. And the package is com.example.android.BluetoothChat, there are 4 directories and in the last one, the BluetoothChat is the file BluetoothChat.java. The Programm is named BluetoothChat, too.

Comment: thanks for your answers.
I fixed it. There was no explicit package in the src directory in eclipse. I only added the dierectories here.